# Who's responsible for calling viewWillLayoutSubviews()/viewDidLayoutSubviews() in a custom UIViewController container?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

When creating a custom `UIViewController` container (a `UIViewController` that contains other UIViewControllers and their views) who is responsible for calling [viewWillLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) and [viewDidLayoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews)? My container class has two sub-controllers of which neither is having these methods called when it moves to the parent view controller.

UIViewController's [beginAppearanceTransition(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/beginAppearanceTransition:animated:) is documented as being the right way to trigger `viewWillAppear()`, `viewWillDisappear()`, `viewDidAppear()`, and `viewDidDisappear()` but I see no equivalent for `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` / `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

As best I can figure the parent view controller (which in this case is being presented via [presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)) is responsible for calling its sub-controllers `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` / `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` in its own implementation of those same methods. The framework seems to call these methods under certain circumstances (like when you set the `rootViewController` property of `UIWindow`) but not others (like when you call `addChildViewController()` in `UIViewController`).

Is this the correct, idiomatic way to go about things?

Answer (score 3):

> who is responsible for calling viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews?

The runtime. You should never call these methods yourself.

Comment: Except the `super` implementation.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear. If it's the runtime then how do you get it to call them on UIViewController objects inside of a custom container?

Comment: The runtime does layout. The runtime will call them. If you think they are not being called then you need to ask a question about _that_, showing that you have added the your view controller and its view correctly etc. But that is not the question you asked; I tried to answer the question you _did_ ask. The answer is: if you are calling them, stop it.

Comment: @IanMacDonald It does say in the documentation that the "super" implementation does nothing. (Although it could be more future proof to call it.)

Comment: OK, but somehow the child `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called AFTER the parent's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  Which is strange, due to the child VC's view is a subview of the partent's view, so it should be layouted first, than the CHILD VC's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` should be called than, and after the PARENT VC's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`... If you get the height of CHILD view in the PARENT `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, than it could be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when the view's bounds changes for any reason. According to [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews):

> When a rotation occurs for a visible view controller, the willRotate(to:duration:), willAnimateRotation(to:duration:), and didRotate(from:) methods are called during the rotation. The viewWillLayoutSubviews() method is also called after the view is resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews() method is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the device orientation.